# django.core.context_processors.request Not working

Tags: django, django-templates

I have this in my `setting.py`:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
)
```

Whenever I try to access the request in a template (for example `{{ request.user.get_profile.custom_username }}`) I get no result. I think the request is not added to the template, because if i force the request in to the Context (in the view), I can access it:

```
ctx = {}
#ctx['request'] = request
return render_to_response('index.html', ctx)
```

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the render shortcut instead, easier to remember:

```
return render(request, 'index.html', ctx)
```

Answer (score 2):

RequestContext needs to be passed to the template, in django 1.3. you can use [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) to automatically include this or if you need to use render_to_response try:

```
return render_to_response('index.html',
                          ctx,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```